# put n balls into n boxes

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose we are given n balls, labeled 1, · · · , n, as well as n boxes, also labeled 1, · · · , n.
We randomly draw one of the n balls and one of the n boxes, and place the ball in the box. This
procedure is repeated n times, until every ball is in a box. Each time the ball is chosen uniformly
from the remaining balls, and the box is chosen uniformly from the remaining boxes.

(a) What is the probability that the ball labeled k ends up in the box labeled k?

(b) What is the expected number of label matches?

(c) What is the variance of the number of label matches?

I think for (a), should it just be 1/n^2? But I think it is not correct, because it is without replacement. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: $\frac{1}{n^2}$ would make sense as an answer of *what is the probability that the FIRST ball drawn was labeled $k$ and further that the box drawn to match was also labeled $k$*.  Here however, we don't care at what time this occurs, just that they were eventually matched together.  Alternatively phrased, you have $n$ different times at which ball $k$ could be matched up with box $k$.  For (b) just use the linearity of expectation.

Comment: If I have n times, should it be $\binom{n}{1}\frac{1}{n^2}$?

Comment: I wouldn't have bothered writing $n$ as $\binom{n}{1}$ but yes that is correct if not a bit wordy.  It simplifies very nicely to simply $\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Would you please explain to me why intuitively 1/n is correct? Thanks.

Comment: For (b), should it just be $\frac{1}{n}\times n = 1$? For (c), should it just be $E(X^2) - (EX)^2 = \frac{1}{n} - 1$?

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{n}-1$ is negative for $n>1$ so it is clearly wrong.  Variances are always non-negative.  More care needs to be taken to calculate $E(X^2)$.  As for an approach, let $\chi_i$ be the binary random variable denoting whether the $i$'th ball is matched with the $i$'th box and note that $X=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\chi_i$ and use this when trying to compute $X^2$ and $E[X^2]$

Comment: Since $E(X) = 1$, then $X$ should be n. So $X^2 = n^2$. So $E(X^2) = n^2 / n = n$. Is that correct now?

Comment: $E(X)=1$ does not imply that $X$ equals $n$ and even if it were your calculations would be way off.  In fact, $E(X)=1$ directly implies that it $X$ is *not* $n$ because otherwise $E(X)$ would equal $n$ instead since $n$ is a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\chi_i$ be the binary random variable representing the event that ball $i$ is placed into box $i$.  That is to say, $\chi_i=\begin{cases}1&\text{if ball}~i~\text{is matched with box}~i\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Question (1) can be rephrased as calculating $Pr(\chi_k=1)$.  As alluded to in the comments we recognize that the arrangement of balls in boxes is precisely a permutation and each position in the permutation is equally likely to be any of the numbers (*or equivalently each box is equally likely to have any of the balls*).  For a more formal explanation, one can approach this with multiplication principle noting that there are $(n-1)!$ ways to arrange balls into boxes satisfying that box $k$ gets ball $k$.  As a result, the probability we are looking for is $Pr(\chi_k=1)=\frac{1}{n}$.

Letting $X$ represent the total number of boxes with their correct balls (*i.e. the number of fixed points in the permutation*) we recognize that $X=\chi_1+\chi_2+\dots+\chi_n$

Question (2) asks us to find $E[X]$ which using the above and linearity of expectation gives us $E[X]=E[\chi_1+\chi_2+\dots+\chi_n]=E[\chi_1]+E[\chi_2]+\dots+E[\chi_n]=n\cdot\frac{1}{n}=1$

Question (3) asks us to find $Var[X]$ which we have the option to expand as $E[X^2]-E[X]^2$.  We already found $E[X]=1$ earlier, so all that remains apart from arithmetic is to calculate $E[X^2]$.  Using that $X=\chi_1+\chi_2+\dots+\chi_n$ again we find:

$$\begin{array}{rl}X^2 &= (\chi_1+\chi_2+\dots+\chi_n)(\chi_1+\chi_2+\dots+\chi_n)\\ &= \chi_1\chi_1+\chi_1\chi_2+\chi_1\chi_3+\dots+\chi_n\chi_{n-1}+\chi_n\chi_n\\
&=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\chi_k^2 + 2\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=k+1}^n\chi_k\chi_j\end{array}$$

We have then $E[X^2]=E\left[\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\chi_k^2 + 2\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=k+1}^n\chi_k\chi_j\right]$ which simplifies quite nicely due to symmetry and properties of binomial random variables.

> $E[X^2]=nE[\chi_1] + 2\binom{n}{2}E[\chi_1\chi_2]$

From here there is one small probability calculation left and then a bit of arithmetic to finish.

> You need to calculate $E[\chi_1\chi_2]$.  Remember that the product of two binary random variables is again a binary random variable and the expected value of a binary random variable is just the probability that the random variable takes the value 1.  That is to say $\chi_1\chi_2=\begin{cases}1&\text{if ball}~1~\text{is in box}~1~\text{and ball}~2~\text{is in box}~2\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ and $E[\chi_1\chi_2]=Pr(\chi_1\chi_2=1)$

---

Continued:

> $Pr(\chi_1\chi_2=1)=Pr(\chi_1=1)\cdot Pr(\chi_2=1\mid \chi_1=1)=\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{n-1}$ (*note, these random variables are dependent on one another*).  We get then $$Var[X]=E[X^2]-E[X]^2=n\cdot\frac{1}{n}+2\binom{n}{2}\frac{1}{n(n-1)}-1=1+1-1=1$$

Answer (score -1):

**Update** (The original answer was wrong, since I had not read the problem carefully. I then overlooked that boxes, once chosen, are taken out of the game as well.)

The described protocol chooses a permutation $\pi\in{\cal S}_n$ uniformly at random. The probability that for a given $k\in[n]$ we have $\pi(k)=k$ then is ${1\over n}$, by symmetry. The linearity of expectation then enforces that the expected number of correct matches is $n\cdot{1\over n}=1$. – Only the computation of the variance necessitates more work.

Comment: Binomial distributions are where every trial occurs with probability $p$ but further and more importantly here, *each trial must be independent of the others*.  These events are not independent.  As a result, we may not assert that $X$ is binomially distributed.  The variance will (*perhaps surprisingly*) not depend on $n$ at all (*assuming that $n\geq 2$*)

Comment: Perhaps you had missed in the question that not only is it that when a ball has been used it is removed and the next time(s) you pick a ball it must be picked from those remaining, but it is also that when you pick a *box* it is also removed and any further choices of boxes must be from those remaining.